# Does Rails 3 have an equivalent to MVC3 Areas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Does Rails 3 have an equivalent to MVC3 Areas? I think I came across it previously but cannot find any information on it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use namespace feature, described in routes.rb

```
     # Sample resource route within a namespace:
     namespace :admin do
       # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
       # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
       resources :products
     end
```

Comment: I've convinced myself that this is correct. For other readers, use the following syntax when generating controllers from the command line: `rails generate controller [namespace]::[controller]`. This will work for models too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use namespace - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/namespace

You can also use a :path_prefix option on a specific route